# Data not writing to MYSQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, database

I'm having trouble with writing information to my database. I was using a method I learned from watching a video on Youtube where we made a `query string` and entered all of the `INSERT INTO` stuff but I'm trying a new way using parameters that I have read to be more secure and protects against SQL injections which I have read to be bad.

I'm using the code below, everything is running fine, no errors, it's connecting to my FTP server and doing all of that fine. My problem is that it's not writing any of the entered user information to the MYSQL database like it was before when I was using the less-secure code.

**Also**, if whoever answers this question knows how to check if the username is already taken in a database, please let me know so I don't have to make a separate question. I've tried something like

```
if(Reader.HasRows) MessageBox.Show("Username Taken");
```

but I got the error `Use of unassigned local variable 'reader'`.

**Code i'm using:**

```
    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    int numerror = 0;
    if (RUsernameTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        numerror = numerror + 1;
    }
    if (RPasswordTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        numerror = numerror + 1;
    }
    if (REmailTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        numerror = numerror + 1;
    }
    if (numerror == 1)
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = "*1 required field is blank.";
    }
    else if (numerror == 2)
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = "*2 required fields are blank";
    }
    else if (numerror == 3)
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = "*3 required fields are blank";
    }
      else
        {
         if (reader.HasRows) CMessageBox("Error", "");
            //add the user to the MySQL database
            string HashedPassword = EncodePassword(RPasswordTextBox.Text);
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=Admin;password=**********";
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO userinfo.users (username,password,email,premium,picture) VALUES (@username, @hashedpassword, @email , @premium , @picture);");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", RUsernameTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hashedpassword", HashedPassword);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", REmailTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@premium", "0");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture","ftp://***.***.*.**/Profile Pictures/" + RUsernameTextBox.Text + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RProfilePicture.ImageLocation) + ".png");

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MakeLoginVisible();
                    try
                    {
                        string TempFolder = Path.GetTempPath();
                        RProfilePicture.Image.Save(@"C:\temp\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RProfilePicture.ImageLocation) + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        ftp ftpclient = new ftp(@"ftp://***.***.*.**/", "Admin", "**********");
                        ftpclient.createDirectory("Profile Pictures/" + RUsernameTextBox.Text);
                        ftpclient.upload("Profile Pictures/" + RUsernameTextBox.Text + "/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RProfilePicture.ImageLocation) + ".png", @"C:\temp\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RProfilePicture.ImageLocation) + ".png");
                        MakeLoginVisible();
                        CMessageBox("Success!", "AirSpace Account '" + RUsernameTextBox.Text + "' Created.");
                        ftpclient = null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        CMessageBox("Error", ex.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    CMessageBox("Error", ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then you can tell us which weird error you got by running the code again? "I got some weird error that I can't seem to remember" is not good enough.

Comment: `I got some weird error that I can't seem to remember` = not useful

Comment: @AndersLindén Sorry for not figuring that out, the error I got when debugging was `Use of unassigned local variable 'reader'`

Comment: You left out a lot of code so I cannot see what the line if(Reader.HasRows) MessageBox.Show("Username Taken"); is preceded with

Answer (score 1):

> Use of unassigned local variable 'xxx'

means that the compiler cannot conclude that you have given a certain variable a value at a given time. Assigning it anything, including null will remove that error message, since then the compiler will know that you have given any thought to the contents of the variable.

Comment: Updated the code with the rest of what I believe to be important.

Comment: MySqlDataReader reader; is the only code that precedes the use of the variable reader. But reader need to contain anything, it should be used to read anything, do you want values to come from a database?

Comment: Yes, I would like the reader to check if the database contains the username that the user is trying to register an account for.

Comment: `string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=Admin;password=**********";` I believe this is the connection to the database. Could you model for me how I would check if the textbox1.text is in the column Username in the table already? That's all I'm really trying to do for that question.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong as I don't directly work MySQL through .net, but in other answer's I've seen, parameters are handled with "?", not "@"